# SQL: How to speed up a query using indexing

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, query-optimization

I am trying to speed up a query to find all CUSTOMERs who have bought a MOTORCYCLE manufactured before 1970 AND bought another MOTORCYCLE manufactured after 2010. Since my query is running very slowly, I think that I need help with finding the better indexes. My attempts are documented below:

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
  id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  fname varchar(30),     
  lname varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE MOTORCYCLE (
  id int PRIMARY KEY, 
  name varchar(30), 
  year int -- Manufactured year
);

CREATE TABLE SALES (
  cid int,
  mid int,
  FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(mid) REFERENCES MOTOCYCLE(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(pid, mid, role)
);
```

**Indexes**

Here are my indexes (I am somewhat guessing with these, but this was my attempt):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customerID on CUSTOMER(id);
CREATE INDEX customerName on CUSTOMER(fname, lname);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX motorcycleID on MOTORCYCLE(id);
CREATE INDEX motorcycleName on MOTORCYCLE(name);
CREATE INDEX motorcycleYear on MOTORCYCLE(year);

CREATE INDEX salesCustomerMotorcycleID on SALES(cid, mid);       
CREATE INDEX salesCustomerID on SALES(cid);
CREATE INDEX castsMotorcycleID on SALES(mid);
```

**Queries**

My query to find the customers purchasing bikes manufactured before 1970 and after 2010 is here:

```
SELECT fname, lname
FROM (SALES INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON SALES.cid=CUSTOMER.id) INNER JOIN MOTORCYCLE ON MOTORCYCLE.id=SALES.mid
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.id
HAVING MIN(MOTORCYCLE.year) < 1970 AND MAX(MOTORCYCLE.year) > 2010;
```

And here is another working query which avoids the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.id, fname, lname
FROM (CUSTOMER as C inner join (SALES as S1 INNER JOIN MOTORCYCLE as M1 ON M1.id=S1.mid) on C.id=S1.cid) inner join (SALES as S2 inner join MOTORCYCLE as M2 on S2.mid=M2.id) on C.id=S2.cid
WHERE (M1.year < 1970 AND M2.year > 2010);
```

Any suggestions on the kinds of indexes I can use to speed up my query? Or should I change my query?

**UPDATE**

I found another query that also works, but it is also too slow. It has been added above. Still, it might be helpful when finding an index to speed it up.

Comment: I think use `JOIN` for query is better way

Comment: I agree - this would be a neater syntax, right? Could a `JOIN` also speed up the query? (I believe it would be an `INNER JOIN ... ON`) I just added it to the OP.

Comment: Why do you use 3 indexes on MOTOCYCLE (year)?

Comment: You are right - it does not speed up the query. I was just trying something out, but I have it removed now. Let me know if you have any suggestions for speeding this up.

Comment: The table `SALES` has no column `pid`, and the last query has no table `C2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check out your queries with [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html), you see that in both cases, the database looks up many related records before it filters out unneeded records (with unwanted years).

The following queries look up the motorcycle IDs before matching; which one is faster depends on the details of your data and must be measured by you:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Sales
              WHERE cid = Customer.id
                AND mid IN (SELECT id
                            FROM Motorcycle
                            WHERE year < 1970))
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Sales
              WHERE cid = Customer.id
                AND mid IN (SELECT id
                            FROM Motorcycle
                            WHERE year > 2010));

SELECT *
FROM Customer
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Sales AS s1
              JOIN Sales AS s2 ON s1.cid = s2.cid
              WHERE s1.cid = Customer.id
                AND s1.mid IN (SELECT id
                               FROM Motorcycle
                               WHERE year < 1970)
                AND s2.mid IN (SELECT id
                               FROM Motorcycle
                               WHERE year > 2010));
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/da91a/5)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Why using group by when there's no using of aggregation function in the query?
Use distinct instead if you don't want to see any duplication

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - I thought that I need the aggregation to know whether the customer has bought a bike outside of the specified range of manufacturing year. So, I am using `GROUP BY` to get the MAX and MIN years of the bikes the customer has purchased. Any suggestions on how to change/improve the query?

Comment: SELECT fname, lname, DISTINCT(CUSTOMER.id)
FROM (SALES INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON SALES.cid=CUSTOMER.id) INNER JOIN MOTORCYCLE ON MOTORCYCLE.id=SALES.mid
WHERE MOTORCYCLE.year < 1970 OR MOTORCYCLE.year > 2010;
This should give you all customers that purchased motorcycle manufactured before 1970 or after 2010

Comment: No, this does not work - I need all customers that purchased a motorcycle manufactured before 1970 AND purchased a motorcycle manufactured after 2010. I am looking for the people who have bought very old AND very new bikes.

Comment: try MOTORCYCLE.year < 1970 AND MOTORCYCLE.year > 2010

Comment: That won't work - after MOTORCYCLE has been joined, both MOTORCYCLE.year instances are referring to the same motorcycle, so `MOTORCYCLE.year < 1970 AND MOTORCYCLE.year > 2010` will never be true.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you.
Now I see what you need...
Try to make 2 views. one for all customers that bought motorcycle before 1970 and the second with all customers that bought a motorcycle after 2010. Then, select distinct (cid) from view1 join view 2 on view1.cid=view2.cid. Try to run that and see if its faster then group by query. Aggregation on numerous rows is never a good idea.